# I need to add +1 for each pressed radio button option and then add its count to mysql database ?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

> Hi everyone,sorry for simple questions but i tried it too long and
>   cant do this.  So the question is this : I have test with three radio
>   options ,and for each option being pressed i want that option to
>   increase on 1 or whatever number i want and then add the count of each
>   radio button being pressed to the database ??? Guys Please help! I
>   have a mysql table named 'test ' with three elements : 'gr' - varchar
>   - 255 - utf8general_ci, 're' - varchar - 255 - utf8general_ci, 'ye' - varchar - 255 - utf8general_ci. So When someones press for example
>   radio button with value green , i want that 'gr' in my sql table 'test
>   ' increase on 1. Guys please explain me all the ways it could be done.

```
    <?php

            $a=mysql_connect('xxxx','xxxx','xxxx');

            $b=mysql_select_db('xxxx',$a);


            if ($_POST){


            if ($_POST['color']=='green'){

            $green=$green+1;

            mysql_query('UPDATE test SET gr='.$green.'');

             }

             if ($_POST['color']=='red'){

            $red=$red+1;

            mysql_query('UPDATE test SET re='.$red.'');

             }

             if ($_POST['color']=='yellow'){

            $yellow=$yellow+1;

            mysql_query('UPDATE test SET ye='.$yellow.'');

             }

             }

            ?>

<form action="http://example.com/indexni.php" method="POST  ">
<input type="radio" name="color" value="green" />Green<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red" />Red<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" />Yellow<br>
<input type ="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change rows type in database to int so rows will be numeric and just replace queries with code given in below example.

```
$query = "UPDATE test SET ye = ye+1;";
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

you hadn't define the $green 's value, is it -255? Also is it set "int" as the type of the fields on the table test? Furthermore, you haven't query the sql statement to mysql. Nejc Rodošek stated the good example for querying the statement.

Here is the sample code for referencing.

```
  <?php
     $a=mysql_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx');
     $b=mysql_select_db('xxx',$a);
     $green = -255; //state the value for updating the value in the       "test"

        $voteTable = "<html>";
             $voteTable .= "<head>";
             $voteTable .= "<meta charset='UTF-8'>";
                  $voteTable .= "<title>color</title>";
             $voteTable .= "</head>";
                  $voteTable .= "<body>";
                        $voteTable .= "<form action='testColor.php' method='POST'>";
                              $voteTable .= "<table border=1>";
                                   $voteTable .= "<tr>";
                                          $voteTable .= "<th colspan=2 > Please choose: </th>";
                                   $voteTable .= "</tr>";
                                   $voteTable .= "<tr>";
                                          $voteTable .= "<td>Green</td>";
                                          $voteTable .= "<td><input type='radio' name='color' value='green' /></td>";
                                   $voteTable .= "</tr>";
                                   $voteTable .= "<tr>";
                                          $voteTable .= "<td>Blue</td>";
                                          $voteTable .= "<td><input type='radio' name='color' value='blue' /></td>";            
                                   $voteTable .= "</tr>";
                                   $voteTable .= "<tr>";
                                          $voteTable .= "<td>Red</td>";
                                          $voteTable .= "<td><input type='radio' name='color' value='red' /></td>";
                                   $voteTable .= "</tr>";
                              $voteTable .= "</table><br/><br/>";
                              $voteTable .= "<br/><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Go!'  /><br/>";
                        $voteTable .= "</form>";
             $colorForm .= "</body>";
        $colorForm .= "</html>";
        echo $colorForm;

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        if ($_POST['color']=='green'){//example of green, blue and red are same with blue
             $green+=1;
             $query = "UPDATE test SET gr='" . $green . "'";
             mysql_query($query);
        }
   }
```

?>